# Is there any other win32api could click/press minimized window?

Tags: python, winapi

The issue link is in https://github.com/mariobarbosa777/minwinpy/issues/2

I tried to use this api to control minimize window, however i could not use the click and press feature in paint or note.

```
    def LeftClick(self, pos, pressTime=0.1):
        """
            Left click in  pos[1],pos[2] during pressTime seconds
            (LButtonDowm, wait a time ,LButtonUp),
        """
        tmp=win32api.MAKELONG(pos[1],pos[2])
        win32gui.SendMessage(self._hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN,win32con.MK_LBUTTON,tmp)
        time.sleep(pressTime)
        win32gui.SendMessage(self._hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP,win32con.MK_LBUTTON,tmp)
```

```
    def PressKey(self, key, pressTime=0.1):
        """
            press key for a time in seconds 
            (KeyDOWN, wait a time ,KeyUP),
            key is a string from VK_CODE
            Lettes in lower case for example "a", "b" , "c"
            F keys in upper case for example "F1", "F2", "F3"
        """
        win32api.SendMessage(self._hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CODE[key], 0)
        time.sleep(pressTime)
        win32api.SendMessage(self._hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP,VK_CODE[key], 0)
        return None
```

Comment: If you want to minimize a window, you can use win32gui.ShowWindow: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__ShowWindow_meth.html with SW_MINIMIZE

Comment: Asking the same question all over again won't change the answer: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PostMessage` or `SendMessage` cannot reliably simulate mouse input. In addition, it won't minimizes the window unless your WinProc responses the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`WM_LBUTTONUP` message and do that.

You can use the [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) api to simulate the mouse click, but only if the minimize button is not covered by other windows.

As comment, there is an easier way to minimize the window without simulation.
[`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) with `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`:

```
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd,win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
```

Comment: Hi, @Yw, does this answer your question? And have you try the `ShowWindow` solution? Please feel free to contact me if you have any issue and also [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it does help.

Comment: Thanks, @Drake Wu is working!! But i dint tried SW_SHOWMINIMIZED